# How can I fetch multiple records in Php?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying for getting multiple records from database but when I try for more then one records. I always getting empty.

First I try FROM DbOperation.php:

```
public function getDayListByDate($DateString){
$stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT DateString FROM gk_eng WHERE DateString= ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$DateString);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
return $result;
}
```

php data get

```
<?php
require_once 'DbOperation.php';
$db = new DbOperation();
$DateString = $_POST['DateString'];
$devices = $db->getDayListByDate($DateString);
$response = array();
$response['error'] = false;
$response['devices'] = array();

while($device = $devices->fetch_assoc()){
$temp = array();
$temp['Question']=$device['Question'];
$temp['Option_2']=$device['DateString'];
array_push($response['devices'],$temp);
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

Response: {"error":false,"devices":[{"Question":null,"Option_2":"10/1/2016 12:00:00 AM"},{"Question":null,"Option_2":"10/1/2016 12:00:00 AM"},{"Question":null,"Option_2":"10/1/2016 12:00:00 AM"}{"Question":null,"Option_2":"10/1/2016 12:00:00 AM"}]}

But when I trying for all records and change database query for getting Question field in reponse like.

```
public function getDayListByDate($DateString){
$stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM gk_eng WHERE DateString= ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$DateString);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->get_result();
return $result;
}
```

I am getting result empty like "".

I am using for connection

```
   function connect()
   {
    //Including the constants.php file to get the database constants
    include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Config.php';

    //connecting to mysql database
    $this->con = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

    //Checking if any error occured while connecting
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    //finally returning the connection link 
    return $this->con;
}
```

Comment: did you try **$stmt->fetchAll()** ?

Comment: Or checked if your query actually matches any records?

Comment: @mmta41 Actually I am new in Php can you explain where I use $stmt->fetchAll()

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php

Comment: For above code how can I use.

Comment: I post code as an answer.

Comment: after using  $stmt->fetchAll()  I getting error huh :(

Answer (score -1):

I think the way you are binding is incorrect too:

```
public function getDayListByDate($DateString){
        $stmt = $this->con->prepare("SELECT * FROM gk_eng WHERE DateString= :DS");
        $stmt->bind_param(":DS",$DateString);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();
        return $result;
    }
```

Comment: Not working, I getting error.

Comment: I test the code without getting error!, what is the error info and Do you use PDO for database connection?

Comment: I am Using     function connect()
    {
        //Including the constants.php file to get the database constants
        include_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/Config.php';
 
        //connecting to mysql database
        $this->con = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);
 
        //Checking if any error occured while connecting
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        }
 
        //finally returning the connection link 
        return $this->con;
    }

Comment: Sorry I miss-leaded you I thought you are using PDO connection but your connection type is mysqli and there is no fetchAll in mysqli connection

Comment: Now what can I do

Answer (score -1):

Try This

```
function getDayListByDate($DateString) {
    $result = $this->con->query("SELECT * FROM gk_eng WHERE DateString='$DateString' ");
    return $result;
}
```

you can get answer.. if didnt get ans .. let me know

Comment: I am using Mysqli

Comment: ok.. i thought PDO ..